# What is a real-world example of block scope being useful in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, scope, var, let

`let` and `const` have introduced block-level scoping to JavaScript, and I now understand the difference. But I'm yet to find a compelling real-world example where `let` has an advantage over `var`.

What does block-scoping offer in practical terms (illustrated by example)?

Comment: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS

Comment: @t3__rry this is a great resource, thanks

Comment: Glad it helped you @DavidR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It creates consistency with other languages:

With `var` it is often quite unclear where a variable is defined and where we can access it and were not:

```
 if(false) {
    var a = 1;
 } else {
    a = 2; // wtf
 }
 alert(a);
```

With `let` its obvious:

```
let a;
if(false) { a = 1; } else { a = 2; }
```

---

2) It allows useful closuring in for loops:

```
 for(var i = 0, i < 10; i++)
   setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 100);
   // 10 10 10 10 ...

 for(let i = 0, i < 10; i++)
   setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 100);
   // 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...
```